# How can I log in to a Mac using an Active Directory account?

Tags: login, active-directory

I have an iMac running OS X 10.7.4. I successfully managed to get the Mac into my company's Active Directory forest using `dsconfigad -add example.com -domain example.com ..`

I am not, however, able to select a user from the AD to log in to the computer. I guess I missed something. Could someone please put my nose into the correct direction?

Answer (score 3):

`dsconfigad -preferred ads01.example.com -a COMPUTERNAME 
–domain example.com -u administrator -p "password"`

For more information just check the manual ([Integrating Active Directory](http://training.apple.com/pdf/Best_Practices_for_Integrating_OS_X_with_Active_Directory.pdf))

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a list of users at the login window (you said "able to select a user") then no, you won't find it unless you can manage MCX on the local machine (then, using Workgroup Manager, go to Preferences tab, Login options, Window tab, and select "show network users"). Otherwise, users have to enter their username (in many forms possible, like DOMAIN\username, DOMAIN\User Name and so on).